# MarkLogic Data Hub Flows Upgrade

Tags: marklogic

I am migrating from Data Hub 4.1.x up to 5.2.x , and was hoping its possible to run scripts to convert existing 4.1.x standard ingestion & harmonization flows into equivalent ingestion & mapping 5.2.x steps.

Can this be done?

If its required to manually re-create everything as steps etc in the new 5.2.x Data Hub version, this could be a large amount of work for developers.
The doco seems to suggest this may be the only option.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not an automated mechanism for doing this. However, you can keep your DHF 4 flows as-is and continue to run them. The reason to shift to a DHF 5 flow is if/when you find value in the OOTB steps - specifically mapping, matching, and merging. Until you see that value, I would keep using the DHF 4 flows.

Comment: Thank you, as always! Does this mean that the Final database data model should be unchanged by the upgrade as well? It sounds like the underlying data handling mechanisms are unchanged - if you can continue to run the old flows?

Comment: That's correct, you can continue to run DHF 4 flows, which are referred to as "legacy flows".